# Overlaying text and graphics (stroked rectangles) on desktop screen

Tags: c++, graphics, accessibility, desktop

For an accessibility desktop application I must overlay the desktop screen with numbers, text and a grid of rectangles (stroked with e.g. red brush).

Ideally this should work on any window manager system (windows, linux KDE/GNOME, possibly even mac).

What is the standard approach to something like this? I was thinking of taking a screenshot of the screen and then drawing on top of it but I'm unsure on what to use to draw.

Comment: There is no standard approach for anything like that. You have to learn the appropriate toolkit for each operating system, and figure out how to use it to accomplish your given task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library that could help you out in making **cross-platform** applications.  [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/), this is capable of making an application window for ***windows, mac, Linux, and more***.
For the graphics stuff, you could use OpenGL or Vulkan(personally not advised for new users) graphics APIs which are cross-platformed.
 *I was thinking of taking a screenshot of the screen and then drawing on top of it but I'm unsure on what to use to draw*. For this you could you framebuffers, [learning OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com).